# District 9: Original Hostile Intent?

Tags: district-9

We can see that they are not passive and can viciously attack and kill humans with cause; but apparently they also cause train crashes (somehow this is cast as a "prank" which makes one wonder what they would do if they were actually angry).

The alien Christopher who created the suit and is apparently a wise scientist/engineer of some sort also apparently is compassionate, not just to his own people but if his promise to Wikus is to be believed, also towards this unfortunate human who in fact is guilty of genocide despite his friendly demeanor.

But the ship is just loaded with weaponry against which humanity would be helpless. The prawns are shown as victims but it seems very plausible that this huge ship was sent to invade and perhaps colonize before some plague (I am guessing) wiped out their leadership. Not clear if Christopher was a remnant of this leadership or what -- I am guessing (again) that he was and I think the implication is that he will return with reinforcements. (Sure would like to see a sequel, worried about the hapless genocidist Wikus as he deals with his transformation.)

Comment: Mining ship; https://io9.gizmodo.com/district-9s-director-tells-us-all-about-his-alien-back-5331799

Comment: with many weapons? are they mining tools and not weapons?

Comment: How do we know they brought the weapons? I assume they were using the ships resources to build them there to trade for cat food. General intelligence for them appears to work very differently than that of humans. They have general nanotech after all.

Comment: @JohnMeacham: no, the fact that the weapons don't work for humans seems inconsistent with your idea. pretty sure the implication is that they had them onboard. but if they can build them from scratch (which, again, i doubt, they are really something in the smarts department.

Comment: Out-of-universe, the ship/weapons is just the McGuffin. Those aliens are about population pressure, not invasion: "_District 9, a violent science fiction movie set in a Johannesburg slum inhabited by 1.8 million feckless refugee space aliens, is the critical and commercial ... hit of the moment ...  _Q.: And you say (Johannesburg is) the future of the world? Why? A: Well, in my opinion, you have out-of-control population growth … we are heading for the biggest train wreck our civilization has ever come across ever ... then you have Joburg in 2050."_ (from "Alien Nation" at Taki's Mag)

Answer (score 3):

### Very doubtful

Yes, the Prawns are far more advanced, but there is very little showing that they have malicious intent

1. The ship doesn't seem to have any capital weapons or smaller vessels that could be used  to harass the opponent.
2. The Number of weapons is insufficient - if I remember correctly, what we see is at best an equivalent of a rifles (which indeed can be a mining tools like @JohnMeacham mentioned). Yes, there are more powerful than what humans have, but any defensive army would have a gigantic numerical superiority, that would have to be countered by enormous firepower which aliens don't have: the few advanced rifles wouldn't do much against a regular army equipped with standard rifles (not counting tanks, planes, artillery etc...).
3. The Prawns are not an army : For an army to be efficient they need to actually follow the orders of their superiors. Yes, the leadership can die, but under each general there are few Majors, then Captains, Lieutenants all the way to Corporals and Privates. If the one on the top is incapacitated, someone replaces him. Of course, it is possible that Prawns fight just using the "horde" style (as in - just kill everything that moves and screw the orders!), but for that they are far too docile.

Imagine that you could go back in time and want to conquer, let's say, XIX Great Britain, but you could take only one ship. You would take a battleship (or even better - a carrier), packed it with disciplined soldiers armed to the teeth. If you were like the Prawns from the movie, instead of a carrier you'd have an old cargo ship and instead of soldiers you'd have a group of refugees. A few smuggled M-16 and AK-47 wouldn't do much against the disciplined army, even equipped only with a single-shooting rifles.

Comment: actually, I read in roald dahl's book about ww2 that a man with a machine gun is worth 500 men with, i think, bolt action rifles. all you would need is a weapon with either greater range or a force field for a single soldier to be able to eventually wipe out an entire army. there are many discussions of how a jet fighter would do in ww1, etc. Anyway, a space-faring civilization could easily have technology that would allow a single invulnerable operator in a control room to destroy, selectively, every army on Earth.

Comment: @releseabe yes, a man with unlimited ammo in defensible position without risk of being outflanked or shot by artillery shooting from behind his range. And in this case there are far too few "machine guns", assuming they are indeed guns able to shoot a continues stream of bullets rather than a single, powerful projectile. Even if they could one-shot a tank, they couldn't one-shot a company of infantry.

Comment: I would not want to gamble on getting into a war with a civilization that has a giant interstellar spacecraft. What if the Prawns (I apologize for the racist term) simply decided to move their ship into an orbit at, say, lunar distance and then began launching 100kg projectiles at  .1 c which I assume they could easily do with their engine technology. What is your plan in that case? Just watch out with whom you pick a fight, buddy. We would be helpless.

Comment: @releseabe again, nothing even remotely suggests that this was their plan. Not mentioning that 100 kg projectile sent with such speed would simply disintegrate in the atmosphere and that hauling around 100 kg of rock is a very inefficient way of conducting warfare.

Comment: I am not sure about disintegration in the atmosphere. Firstly, I did not make up this idea of using very fast, non-explosive projectiles as a weapon. Secondly, objects from space do penetrate the atmosphere and occasionally reach the ground. Thirdly, while the increased speed (no meteor moves at anywhere near .1c would result in greater heating, the speed also means it would spend less time in the atmosphere -- I think it takes some serious analysis before we know whether an object will reach the ground or not. Maybe you have seen this sort of analysis but I have seen simulations with impact.